# Can't Remove Contact Information in Test Information Under Testflight in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to transfer an app from my account to another and i am stuck with the last criteria "You must remove all builds and testers from the app you want transferred and clear each information field below Test Information" . I have removed all the builds and testers from the app , but i am unable to clear the test information field such as firstname,lastname , contact number and email . [image: Unable to clear this info]. I am unable to proceed to transfer app because of this, suggest your valuable comments to solve this

Comment: how is this swift or objective-c question?

Answer (score 2):

Just now, Apple called me and said that they had solved the problem. You need to log out and log in again to the developer account, then you can delete the contact information. Now I have initiated the transfer application.

Answer (score 0):

Not required to remove **Beta App Review Information** for app transfer process. Just TestFlight beta testing should be turned off for all beta versions of the app.

**App transfer criteria**

Before an app can be transferred it has to meet the following criteria:

```
•   Both accounts can’t be in a pending or changing state, and the latest version of the agreements in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking section must be accepted.
•   No version of the app can use an iCloud entitlement.
•   No version of the app can use a Passbook entitlement.
•   The App must have had at least one version that has been released to the App Store.
•   In-app purchase product IDs on the app can’t be the same as product IDs on any apps in the recipient’s account.
•   TestFlight beta testing should be turned off for all beta versions of the app.
•   Sandboxed Mac apps that share the Application Group Container Directory with other Mac apps cannot be transferred.
```

Follow the [guideline](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devaf27784ffhttps://) and [this document](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account) for more information.